# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I'm trying to use "TextInputLayout" with "TextInputEditText".
I've gone over the posts in stackoverflow and nothing helped yet.

Here's my VERY simple code -

XML design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_card_expiration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:hint="crap"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</TextInputLayout>
```

Inflation code (In my fragment):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_purchase, container, false);
}
```

While running, returns the following exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class TextInputLayout
                                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class TextInputLayout
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.javaproject.pashnim.pashnimcinema-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.javaproject.pashnim.pashnimcinema-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:700)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                         at com.javaproject.pashnim.cinema.PurchaseFinishFragment.onCreateView(PurchaseFinishFragment.java:23)
```

or in short:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.view.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.javaproject.pashnim.pashnimcinema-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.javaproject.pashnim.pashnimcinema-1/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

Remarkes:

1. I'm running Android Studio 3.0 Canary V9
2. Gradle version: "3.0.0-alpha9"
3. I've added the dependency required:

> compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

4. Tried Cleaning Rebuilding the project.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to use the fully-qualified class name in the tag, just like you did for the `TextInputEditText` – `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout ...`.

Comment: @MikeM. wow that was silly of me! it worked :) Thank you!